# Getting status 500 when posting data to MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next.js13

When sending my data using the api that I created in the pages folder, I get a 500 status and the following error:
**POST http://localhost:3000/api/new-meetup 500 (Internal Server Error)**
But whenever I look at my code, I don't see any problem with the code

'pages/api/new-meetup.js'

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";


const handler = async (req, res) =>
{
    console.log(req, res);
    const connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.wog45jo.mongodb.net/meetups?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    if (req.method === 'POST')
    {
        try
        {
            const data = req.body;

            const client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString);
            const db = client.db();
            const meetupsCollection = db.collection('meetups');
            const result = meetupsCollection.insertOne(data);

            console.log(result);
            client.close();

            res.status(201).json({ massage: 'Meetup Inserted' })
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

}

export default handler;
```

'pages/new-meetup/index.jsx'

```
import NewMeetupForm from "@/components/meetups/NewMeetupForm"
import axios from "axios";

const newMeetupPage = () =>
{

    const addMeetupHandler = async (enteredMeetupData) =>
    {
        const response = await axios({
            url:'/api/new-meetup', 
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({enteredMeetupData}),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }

    return (
        <NewMeetupForm onAddMeetup={addMeetupHandler} />
    )
}

export default newMeetupPage
```